# How to get Response Header Cookies?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension tries to log me in on a certain website when a login button is present. I now want to add a check if the login failed, so the script doesnt loop and instead I can handle it in some other way. I looked at the differences of a failed and succesful login and noticed the "Location" and "Set-Cookie" headers are different.

But I can't access neither of these. Location seems not to work in any case, Set-Cookie on the other hand says "Refused to get unsafe content header". As I don't own the server, I also can't change anything about the headers I get. Is there any way I can still access them?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://loginpage.com/login?login=1&password=2", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
var cookies = xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

if(cookies.includes("auth=")) {
    everythingworks();
} else {
    wrongcredentials();
}
}
};
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the response of the `https://loginpage.com/login?login=1&password=2` instead of cookies?

Comment: I assume this is a CORS issue. the owner of the server doesn't allow CORS.

Comment: You can fetch the response in your [onload Xml function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload) as xhr.response or xhr.responseText (if you wanted in text format).

Example from [XMLHttpRequest.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)

Additional reading: [W3 Schoos XML HttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) and [Mozilla XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). For CORS related subjects, check [CORS](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr)